# Scheduling scripts with variable frequency

Tags: linux, shell, cron, server

I want to run a python script on a ubuntu 14.04 server with following frequency:

- Monday to Friday:

  - From 0800 hrs to 1600 hrs: Run once every hour
  - From 1600 hrs to 2300 hrs: Run once every 30 minutes
- Saturday and Sunday:

  - From 0800 hrs to 2300 hrs: Run once every two hours
- At other times, don't run

Is this possible with cron? If not, can anybody suggest some alternative?

Comment: Sure that is possible. You create three separate cron entries for the groups you sketched.

Comment: Or, alternatively, run it every 30 minutes regardless, and put logic in the beginning of the script to decide if it should exit early or continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, adding these cron entries will do:
(Lines starting with # are comments)

```
# monday to friday, 8 am to 4 pm, once every hour
0 8-16 * * 1-5 <command>
# monday to friday, 4 pm to 10 pm, twice every hour
0,30 17-22 * * 1-5 <command>
# saturday to sunday, 8 am to 11 pm, once every hour
0 8-23 * * 0,6 <command>
```